# Problem with url_launcher package (Flutter)

Tags: gradle, flutter

I’m working on a Flutter project. I’m starting with the counter app. If a use the following packages, I have not any problem:

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
flutter_markdown: ^0.3.3
google_fonts: ^0.3.9
google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.23+1
intl: ^0.16.1
provider: ^4.0.4
rive: ^0.0.1
rxdart: ^0.23.1
shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+1
```

But if I use the `url_launcher: ^5.4.1` package, I receive this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':url_launcher:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':url_launcher:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :url_launcher
      [...]
```

How can I solve? Thank you!

Comment: The error appears only after a complete rebuild of the app.

Comment: You can downgrade it to 5.3.0. It work well

Comment: add output of : flutter channel

Comment: also try flutter clean and then again build your project.

Comment: @hoangquyy I have the same problem with version `5.2.7`.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya the output of `flutter channel` is:

```Flutter channels:
  beta
  dev
  master
* stable```

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya, also after run `flutter clean` I have the same problem. Can anyone recommend an online service where I can share the entire error message? Stack Overflow does not allow me to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version `5.4.2` of the package the problem seems to be solved.